# A harmoinic oscillator in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Considering the Hamiltonian of a harmonic oscillator
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2 x^2}{2},
\end{equation}
the time evolution of the Heisenberg picture position and momentum operators is given by
\begin{align}
 \dot{x}&=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,x]=\frac{p}{m}\\
 \dot{p}&=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,p]=-m\omega^2x,
\end{align}
from which we get
\begin{align}
 \ddot{x}=\frac{\dot{p}}{m}=-\omega^2 x.
\end{align}
We can solve this differential equation with an initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ to obtain
\begin{align}
 x=x_0 e^{-i\omega t}.
\end{align}
On the other hand, $p$ may be calculated by inserting $x=x_0 e^{-i\omega t}$ into $\dot{x}=\frac{p}{m}$ as the form
\begin{align}
 p=-im\omega x_0 e^{-i\omega t},
\end{align}
but it does not seem to be quantum mechanical because $p$ is represented in terms of $x_0$, so $p$ can commute with $x$. Where I am wrong?

Comment: $x$ and $p$ should be operator. Your solution make sense for expectation value only. (Note that expectation value follows classical motion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not imposing the initial conditions correctly. The initial conditions are:
\begin{align}
x(0)&=x_0=x_S, \text{ and} \\
p(0)&=p_0=p_S.
\end{align}
That is, at $t=0$ the Heisenberg and Schrödinger picture operators coincide. So, the solution to this ordinary differential equation (ODE) for $x(t)$
$$\ddot{x}=-\omega^2x$$
is
$$x(t) = A(x_0,p_0)\cos(\omega t)+B(x_0,p_0)\sin(\omega t). \tag1$$
Plugging $t=0$ into (1) produces
$$A(x_0,p_0)=x_0.$$
Locking down $B$ requires using the equation
$$\dot{x} = \frac{p}{m}$$
giving
$$p = -mx_0\omega\sin(\omega t) +mB(x_0,p_0)\,\omega\cos(\omega t). \tag2$$
Plugging $t=0$ into (2) leads to
$$B(x_0,p_0)=\frac{p_0}{m\omega}.$$
Thus the Heisenberg picture operators are:
\begin{align}
    x(t) & = x_0 \cos(\omega t) + \frac{p_0}{m\omega}\sin(\omega t),\ \text{and} \\
    p(t) & = - m\omega x_0\sin(\omega t) + p_0 \cos(\omega t).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your solution $ x = x_0 e^{-i\omega t}$ is not complete. The equation you are solving is second degree. It should depend two initial values $ x = x_0 e^{-i\omega t}+ x_1 e^{+i\omega t}$